# Android - RFID's EPC hex bank fills with nulls

Tags: java, android, rfid

I m trying to write data to EPC bank.

For example i have: String data where i have stored "dataaa".

I need to convert data variable to hex, that is okay, the output of these data is well encrypted to hex, but when i write it to bank - there are 14 times 0 on the start and then starts my hex data.

The question is, how to store only the HEX string to EPC but without nulls?

Hex function:

```
char[] chars = asciiStr.toCharArray();
StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : chars) {
    hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) ch));
}

return hex.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPC Memory accepts only even length text and then makes an hex from it.
So i need to check if text to store in EPC is even, and if not i have added extra " "(space) to it.Then the length of a text is even so i am able to convert and write converted HEX value to EPC memory.